# React useState Error, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am getting the error [react.development.js:1501 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html), I am using it at the top of a Function Component, my React version and ReactDOM version are both 17.0.1. I have only react imported once. And I believe I am following all the rules. When I search the error I keep getting all the suggestions and rules that the React documentation already describes. But I also have another component that uses state and doesn't throw this error.
Here is my Code.

```
const { useState } = React;

export default () => {
    const [list, setList] = useState([]);

    return (
        <datalist id="themes">{
            list.map((item, index) => {
                return <option value={item} key={index} />
            })
        }</datalist>
    );
}
```

In my example `React` is a global variable, I am including it via a CDN.

Comment: I think the linter may be getting hung up on the default export of an anonymous function. Try giving it a name first, `const MyComponent = () => ...` then export it, `export default MyComponent;`.

Comment: Pretty sure drew is right, you can only use hooks in react components or hooks (functions starting with 'use'). Since this doesn't have a name at all, linter doesn't realise that it is actually a component and thinks it's just a regular JS function, where hooks aren't allowed

Comment: I am not using a linter, the thing that really gets me is that I have another component almost 100% identical in every way and that doesn't error. As a matter of fact when i copy and paste that code in here so it is 100% identical, i still get the error, but only on this component and not the other.

Comment: I updated it to use a named real function (instead of an arrow function) and it still shows this error.

Comment: Ok, maybe not the linter that ships with CRA now, but react still does hook validation when running in non-production builds. Could you try creating a running codesandbox or similar, or even just a *runnable* code snippet here (you can use react!) that we may debug on?

Comment: Can you show both functions, the one that produces the error and the one that doesn't? I don't see anything wrong with this code.

Comment: When i say they are literally i mean they can be litterally 100% exactly the same, character for character. I am showing both functions

Comment: Did naming it/them fix the problem? I don't see how you could wind up with two different results for the exact same deterministic code run on the exact same environment.

Comment: No, that did not fix the issue. I found a solution and posted it as an answer. Basically one was being rendered directly, and one was being rendered as a subcomponent. For some reason `useState` does not work when the component is rendered directly. Apparently no one has ever found this bug before because i cant find it anywhere online.

Comment: How are you rendering this component? Are you using the jsx syntax <DataList />, or calling it as a function dataList()? If it's the latter, then it's not being treated as a "react component". If you share that part of the code, this should help us provide advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between one component working and the component not working had nothing to do with the component itself. But rather how it was rendered. If I rendered it directly, it gave this error. If I simply wrapped it in another component that didn't use state and then rendered it, it worked fine.

`FetchedDataList.jsx`

```
const { useState } = React;

export default () => {
    const [list, setList] = useState([]);

    return (
        <datalist id="themes">{
            list.map((item, index) => {
                return <option value={item} key={index} />
            })
        }</datalist>
    );
}
```

`Wrapper.jsx`

```
import FetchedDataList from './FetchedDataList.js';

export default (props) => {
    return <FetchedDataList {...props} />
}
```

`app.js`

```
import Wrapper from './wrapper.jsx';

React.render(Wrapper, document.body);
```

This seems to work perfectly fine. So apparently you're not allowed to directly render components that use state? I don't see that in their documentation.

Comment: This is because render is directly calling the function Wrapper - you should be passing `React.render(<FetchedDataList />, document.body)`

Comment: What does "render it directly" mean? You never did share how working and non-working components were being rendered. I still think it was react viewing the anonymous function as a function versus a react component.

Comment: `ReactDOM.render(Component, document.body)` is rendering directly and does not work, where as rendering a wrapper component that renders my component is working.

I am exporting unnamed functions and its working fine, so I guarantee you that is not a problem, at least with React 17.

Answer (score -1):

Name your react functional component.

```
const { useState } = React;
export default Mycomponent () => {
const [list, setList] = useState([]);

return (
    <datalist id="themes">{
        list.map((item, index) => {
            return <option value={item} key={index} />
        })
    }</datalist>
);
```

}